# Retargeting Mocap Upside Down and Weird

Tags: animation, rigging, add-on, motion-capture

I'm new to Blender (coming from Cinema 4D mainly). I can't figure out how to correctly retarget a mocap rig I got from Mixamo onto a simpler rig.

Before retargeting:
[image: Before retarget]
After retargeting:
[image: After retarget]
Using a walking-while-holding-a-gun animation:
[image: Gun walking]

I would appreciate if someone could help me figure out the following:
1) Why it makes my rig upside down or perpedicular to the mocap animation
2) Why the animation is not correctly followed as seen in the provided GIF

Here is the blender file which I think should help in figuring this out:
https://files.fm/u/zxke6d27

## **EDIT:**

I've gotten it to this point:
[image: New gif showing body part correlation]
What I'm not sure about how the rigs have their joints point in the same direction yet correlate to the parts as if they were rotated 180 degrees. Here's the current file:
https://files.fm/u/nh88zr4j

Comment: Blender inludes an addon called "Motion Capture tools" which includes a "Fix bvh axis rotation". Generally blender uses z-up which often conflicts with other software, when importing bvh you have options to change the axis orientations.